# How to get MouseHover to fire faster or more repeatedly on the same form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 128 small forms all arranged in one bigger FlowLayoutPanel. Each of the 128 forms have their own onPaint overriden:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (CustomSquare cs in this.customSquares)
        {
            this.formGraphics.FillRectangle(cs.colorBrush, cs.boundingRectangle);
        }
    }
```

And each table has MouseHover implemented:

```
    public void customView_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("greetings from table " + this.getTableNumber());
    }
```

Now the event handler fires repeatedly and easily when the mouse switches BETWEEN tables like so:

```
greetings from table 3
greetings from table 0
greetings from table 3
greetings from table 0
greetings from table 1
```

But it's very hard to get the EventHandler to fire on the same table repeatedly with small mouse movements or movements that say internal to the same table's dimensions like so:

```
greetings from table 0
greetings from table 0
greetings from table 0
```

The main functionality of the program requires that I know very frequently and consistently which of the 128 forms the user's mouse is in and using the MouseHover event seemed the best way but I would like it to fire more frequently.

Comment: wpf **or** winforms? Surely not both?

Comment: Use MouseMove instead of MouseHover.

Comment: I will check out MouseMove Hans thanks. Unfotunately I've managed to write c# code that's freezing my entire PC. Need to revert apparently real quick.

Comment: May I ask what't this for? and also a picture would help to figure out what it's like

Comment: I'm representing data via colored squares and I want to query an array to display that value when the user mouses over the square that represents that value. i wasn't querying repeatedly enough with MouseHover but MouseMove is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hans Passant had the correct answer.

Changing from MouseHover to MouseMove gave me very fast reaction times by the event firer.